# Ajax Calls with Fetch API in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, fetch-api

I just migrated to .NET Core 3.1 and among the different things I had to update I can't get my ajax calls to work.

When I make an ajax call, none of the data binds to the object parameter in my action.

This is how I am making the call in my razor page

```js
fetch('/Administration/UpdateUserStatus', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'RequestVerificationToken': $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
```

And my controller action

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateUserStatus([FromBody]User user) {
    ...
}
```

In my example code above, debugging the code I can see that `user` comes in as `null`, so the data from the ajax call does not bind to the `User` object.

If I remove `[FromBody]`, `user` does not come in as `null` anymore, but the data still doesn't bind. All the properties as either null or the default value.

Everything was working fine in .NET Core 2.1.

Is it something I need to add in `Startup.cs`? Maybe a new configuration I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: The first thing to check is to compare the requests in both versions and see whether any difference .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my issue. Json.NET was removed from .NET Core 3.0 so I had to add a reference to package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` (NuGet) then under the `ConfigureServices` method add `.AddNewtonsoftJson()` to Razor Pages, like so

```cs
services.AddRazorPages().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

After that, everything is working as before.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support)

Comment: Oh God, you saved me!

Comment: Thank you! Spent quite a bit of time trying to understand why model binding was failing on my AJAX POST request. I am confused by the docs because I was under the impressions that System.Text.Json will handle the model binding...

Comment: Found this helpful post that explains further: https://dev.to/wattengard/why-your-posted-models-may-stop-working-after-upgrading-to-asp-net-core-3-1-4ekp

Comment: After two days I finally found this answer. Thanks